# Can you prevent a permanent from untapping with a tapping ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In a match against someone (a professional), I was faced with a [Tyrant's Machine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTyrant%27s%5d%2b%5bMachine%5d). He tapped my best creature and he said that my permanent never untapped, not even during my untap step. Needless to say, I lost. Was he correct?

Comment: Yeah... that "professional" was either lying to you or is really not as "professional" as he seems to believe.

Comment: The current answer is correct based on how your question is worded, but from your question the specifics of the situation that caused you to lose aren't entirely clear. For instance if your opponent had an untapped Tyrant's Machine at the beginning of your turn, they would have been able to tap your creature before combat and you would still be unable to attack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No.**

All of your permanents untap during your untap step unless an effect has specifically said they do not untap or that you can choose not to untap them. Tyrant's Machine has neither of those effects.

Comment: For example, see [Giant Oyster](http://magiccards.info/tsts/en/22.html).

Comment: I was going to edit the answer with the relevant rules quote, but interestingly, I believe that would make it sound less clear than what's already here. For anyone looking for it, the relevant rule is CR 502.2

Answer (score 0):

This would actually depend on which phase he tapped your creature in. The phases of a turn go in this order:

> Untap > Upkeep > Draw > Main > Combat > Main > End

So there is a point, between your untap and draw step, in which he could tap your creature until your next turn. This explanation does not account for him saying that the creature didn't untap during your untap step. There could also have been some other effect on the board that would stop your creature from untapping during your untap step (aka hard tapped). However, without knowing the rest of the board state, that is impossible to tell.

Comment: The question states that they are wondering about the entirety of the game, not the rest of the turn. Even if you tap the creature after this turns' untap step, it will untap in the *next* turns' untap step, as explained by another answer.

Comment: @TheThirdMan The way I read the question was that he "never untapped" on his turn, so I see what you mean. Regardless, the point stands that there could be some other effect on the board that would stop his creature from untapping.

Comment: True, but if you were to assume that, you could make any question infinitely complex. It's generally sensible to assume that what's stated is everything that's relevant to the situation (which wil also provide the most useful answers), and only stray from that principle when the question is as broad as "How could I do (...)".